# inner join on two select queries in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table

```
id empid  reaction        date_t
1  emp090 not_interested  2017-09-16
2  emp090 not_interested  2017-09-16
```

I am looking to count the number of reaction as per the `empid` and `date_t`.
I have tried this query

```sql
SELECT c.COUNT(reaction) as interested,c.empid FROM `cases` c 
WHERE c.reaction="interested" and c.empid="EMP12654" 
  AND c.date_t BETWEEN  "2017-09-15"  AND "2017-09-18" 
INNER JOIN 
( SELECT cases.empid COUNT(reaction) not interested FROM `cases` 
  WHERE cases.reaction="not_interested" and cases.empid="EMP12654" 
    AND cases.date_t BETWEEN  "2017-09-15"  AND "2017-09-18" ) 
AS alpha on alpha.empid=c.empid;
```

Can anyone tell me how to do it correctly?

Comment: COUNT(c.reaction) - or, more likely, COUNT(0). Also look again at query syntax.

Comment: If you're still struggling, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I corrected that but it still giving me error ,"you have error near inner join"

Comment: Incidentally, storing 'EMP' is going to be a real headache.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
SELECT empid, count(reaction) as count, date_t
FROM cases
WHERE reaction="interested" AND empid="EMP12654" 
AND date_t BETWEEN "2017-09-15" AND "2017-09-18" 
GROUP BY empid, date_t;
```

Comment: Missed it @Strawberry. I have updated it. You could have also done the same by updating my answer instead of down voting it.

Comment: That wouldn't have been as much fun.

Comment: Hahahah. Too good. Hope to see you around

Answer (score 0):

The error in your query is related  to several error :  wrong sequence between where an join clause,
 missing table name for inner join subselect, missing comma between column name in subquery, missing on clause

but if you want only the count of interested for date_t and empid

You can use group by eg:

```
  SELECT  
         c.empid
       , c.date_t
       , c.COUNT(*) as interested
  FROM `cases` c 
  WHERE  WHERE c.reaction="interested" 
  AND c.empid="EMP12654" 
  AND c.date_t BETWEEN  "2017-09-15"  AND "2017-09-18"
  GROUP BY  c.empid, c.date_t
```